# Web Design; Same Object on Multiple Pages?

Tags: php, html, css, web-deployment

I apologize of this question has been asked before. I tried searching around, but was unable to find a relevant answer (probably due to my relatively small "web-design vocabulary").

I've noticed that the majority of websites have at least one--if not more--standard "objects" (or whatever the actually name is for them) on almost all of their pages. For instance, Stack Overflow has the same logo and tabs (Questions, Tags, Users...) on every page. I'm assuming that there's a less painstaking way to set this up other than simply copying and pasting the same code over and over, especially when ease of modification becomes a factor. As far as I know, CSS can't do accomplish this level of style generalization, so I'm assuming a server-sided language like PHP is part of the equation.

I'm not really looking for a very specific answer. What language--or type or language--as well as a brief synopsis of at least one way to achieve some sort of "object pasting" will be sufficient.

Comment: You use `include('linked/file/here.php')` to include the same elements into your page. Also, `require()`, `include_once()` etc. [INCLUDE IN THE PHP MANUAL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Comment: You can do this in many languages including old and plain HTML. You can use `frames` to do it. But if you are looking for a responsive language, yes, I would recommend PHP. It will be simple to learn. Like @Rasclatt said look for the include `command`. Ooh, you can do this with css :) you just need to add a line of code to your page :)

Answer (score 3):

Like others said, this is a major reason why people go from HTML to something like PHP, at first just to split up parts of your page.

Yes, you can do exactly that. What I usually do (if I'm not using a framework) is create a folder in my directory like this:

```
inc/header.php
inc/footer.php
inc/menu.php
index.php
```

Then in `index.php` you'd need an include like:

```
<? include('inc/header.php'); ?>
<h2>Welcome to my site</h2>
<p>We're happy to have you</p>
<? include('inc/footer.php'); ?>
```

And in `inc/header.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <title>My site</title>
   </head>
   <body>
```

And in `inc/footer.php`:

```
<div id="footer">
    <h2>Thanks for visiting</h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And so on for `inc/menu.php`

Then for other pages on your site, do the same `includes` for header, footer, and menu, and just write your page-specific content between the includes

Answer (score 3):

Just an alternative to PHP:

Use Javascript or [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

```
$( "#footer" ).load( "includes/footer.html" );
```

Another alternative is to use [SHTML](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/s/shtml.htm), which is basically HTML with inserts.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do this is to create separate files for different sections of your page then instead of pasting the same code on each page use

```
include ('yourfilename.php');
```

to add the code in yourfilename.php at that point in the php file.  This also makes it easy to modify that section and have your changes be reflected on all the pages that use yourfilename.php

For example, you can make one file called page_top.php and another called page_bottom.php.  Then on each of your various php pages you can include('page_top.php'); near the top and include('page_bottom.php'); near the bottom.  The code within these files will then be executed on each of your content pages.

There are of course other methods but this is a super easy way and you should look into this first.

Answer (score 2):

An example of include would be:

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<stuff><stuff>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mybanner">Design and logo that is common on all pages</div>
```

**content/contact.php**

```
<div id="bulk_of_the_html">
The rest of your stuff goes here
</div>
```

**foot.php**

```
<div id="footer_common_to_all">This is your footer content that is common to all pages</div>
</body>
</html>
```

To use would be something like:

**contact.php**

```
// This is your common to all pages header
include("header.php");
// This can be changed up as content switches
include("content/contact.php");
// This is your common to all pages footer
include("foot.php");
```

Answer (score 2):

[HTML imports](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/tutorials/webcomponents/htmlimports) or [Webcomponents](http://webcomponents.org/) is a new way to do this completely at client side using HTML, JS and CSS. Write a component and reuse it in every page. But it uses [ShadowDom](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/dom/shadowdom), means not search indexable yet.

```
<link rel="import" href="header-banner.html">
<!-- use this in body -->
<header-banner></header-banner>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two solutions

1. Use include('....php') or require('....php') or include_once('....php') or require_once('....php') php functions to add external sections/modules into your web page(php).
   You can call this functions at the position where you want the extremal module/part to be appeared.

   ```
     include("Header.php");   // call to external module

     // your body goes here
     <h1>.......</h1>
     <p>........</p>
     .....................

     include("Footer.php");    // again to another module
   ```
2. Or its better if you can go for a MVC framework where you can combine multiple modules and views into one output page...(ex Codeignitor/Cakephp...)

Comment: require_once() is expensive and unnessecary for HTML includes. there's no reason to use anything other than include().

Comment: yes agree. but all these functions have their own characteristics.